# Postgres error: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am aware that this question has been asked many times however, I'm unable to figure out what's wrong in spite of following the SO answers. Would appreciate the help as I'm new to PostgreSQL. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Using pgadmin4, I created a database. From there, I right-clicked on procedures and created a new procedure using the GUI. I set language as SQL in the definition tab and then wrote the following code in the code tab

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE f_data(IN arg1 integer, IN arg2 integer)
    
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (arg1, arg2);
$$;
```

2. Clicking save didn't raise any errors, so I right-clicked on the newly created procedure, and then from the scripts menu, I clicked on EXEC Script. That generated the following code

```
CALL public.f_data(1, 2)
```

Running this raised the following error statement

```
ERROR:  procedure public.f_data(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: CALL public.f_data(1::integer, 2::integer)
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 6
```

I also tried

```
CALL public.f_data(1::integer, 2::integer)
```

Received the same error mentioned above.

Where am I going wrong? Will only mark an answer as accepted with clearly-detailed steps.

Comment: You code looks just fine. Perhaps is the procedure being created in a another schema? To be sure, try: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.f_data(IN arg1 integer, IN arg2 integer)`. Does it solve your problem? https://dbfiddle.uk/MTkiWpIg

Comment: @JimJones Thank you for your comment. However, the issue was something else. I have solved it and have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. Using the GUI to create a procedure is a terrible way of doing things. I realized that the GUI offers 2 more tabs - parameters and SQL. A quick inspection of the SQL tab revealed the following code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.f_data()
    LANGUAGE sql
    
AS $$
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE f_data(IN arg1 integer, IN arg2 integer)
    LANGUAGE sql
    INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (arg1, arg2);
$$;
```

Basically, the code I had written in the code section of the GUI, ended up getting included in the body of the stored procedure. You might also notice that the 1st line of the code has no parameters. I tried to add parameters using the parameters tab, however, it doesn't seem to allow custom parameters.

Anyway, I ditched the idea of using the GUI to create a procedure and opened a new query editor, and wrote the same code I posted in the question and it worked this time around.

**EDIT**

If you want to set input parameters for your stored procedure using the GUI, you must do it in the definition tab.